# Building sphinx documentation in subversion via locally hosted readthedocs.org server

Tags: svn, python-sphinx, devops, documentation-generation, read-the-docs

I have a bunch of Python projects in my company, with subversion as my VCS.

I want to build and host the sphinx documentation for each of these projects using a locally hosted readthedocs.org server, but I've run into a problem.

I've used the documentation provided [here](https://docs.readthedocs.io/) and served up the rtd server. But [importing subversion repositories](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/import-guide.html) isn't documented too well. For one thing, it seems to prefer the http/https protocol, and we use the svn:// protocol here. I am not so sure I can switch.

The UI doesn't allow URLS with an `svn://` prefix, and I don't know how to continue from here. I've found an [old Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/read-the-docs/hE3bA-cEkoU) relate to this but it doesn't seem to help so much.

Has anyone attempted to get a configuration of rtd and svn working together? The example that is linked to in the Google Groups discussion has since seemingly shifted to github.